# Random errors with Threads and Hibernate sessions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im using hibernate3 and spring.

Java code:

Class CommunicationServiceImpl, method sendAllMessages:

```
Collection<MessageToSend> messagesToSend = this.repositoriesLocator.getMessageToSendRepository().getMessagesToSend();


        Iterator<MessageToSend> iteratorMesToSe = messagesToSend.iterator();
        while (iteratorMesToSe.hasNext()) {
            MessageToSend mts = iteratorMesToSe.next();

            MessageSender sender = new SmsSender(mts, this.repositoriesLocator);
            sender.start(); //run thread                
        }
```

SmsSender:

```
public class SmsSender extends MessageSender {

public SmsSender(MessageToSend messageToSend, RepositoriesLocator repositoriesLocator) {
    super(messageToSend, repositoriesLocator);      
}

public void sendMessages() {            
    try {
        MessageToSendSms messageToSendSms = (MessageToSendSms) this.messageToSend;                                                      
        Iterator<CustomerByMessage> itCbmsgs = messageToSendSms.getCustomerByMessage().iterator();          
        while (itCbmsgs.hasNext()) {                
            CustomerByMessage cbm = (CustomerByMessage) itCbmsgs.next();        

            //sms sending                           
            String sResult = this.sendSMS(cb.getBody(), cbm.getCellPhone());
            cbm.setStatus(CustomerByMessageStatus.SENT_OK);
            cbm.setSendingDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());                               
        }

        messageToSendSms.setStatus(messageToSendStats.PROCESSED)
        this.log.info("saving messageToSend..."); 
        //this line dont work!
        this.repositoriesLocator.getMessageToSendRepository().update(messageToSendSms);         
        this.log.info("messageToSend saved!");                      
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        this.log.error("Error sms sender " + e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

This is a part of my appContext.xml:

```
<bean id="serviceCommunication"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref local="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="target">
        <ref local="communicationServiceImpl" />
    </property>             
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="communicationServiceImpl"
    class="com.ninatec.fnet3.services.communication.impl.CommunicationServiceImpl"
    parent="serviceParent">
</bean>
```

HibernateRepository
repositoriesLocator.getMessageToSendRepository().update CODE:

```
public void update(MessageToSend messageToSend) {
    try {
        this.getSession().update(messageToSend);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        this.log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The entity MessageToSend, has never been updated.

When I invoke CommunicationServiceImpl.sendAllMessages()  I have in a collection all messagesToSend.
For each MessageToSend I make a Thread to send the message.
The Thread smsSender works good, but not the persistence in the data base. Changes in the object MessageToSend has not been updated in my database.

Randoms errors are:

session closed,

could not initialize proxy - no Session,

could not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed,

Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions in hibernate and

failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: no session or session was closed

---

- - about the thread. I want to use one thread for x sms. Every smsSender, send a group of sms.

I dont understand how detach the objects from session explicitly in my architecture.

Comment: Try to create a simpler version of the code that exposes the problem for more help.

Comment: Where in your code are the errors happening?  What steps have you taken to try and resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing very bad things with threads and Hibernate sessions. First of all `CommunicationServiceImpl.sendAllMessages()` is transactional. This means `MessageToSend` entity is connected to Hibernate session while you iterate over `messagesToSend` collection. That's fine.

However for each entity you start new thread<sup>*</sup> which processes that entity. Inside that thread you perform a lot of computations on `MessageToSend`, including some sub-queries and updates. This is where dangerous race condition manifests:

If the thread started while we are still inside the main `while (iteratorMesToSe.hasNext())` loop (we are still inside `sendAllMessages()` method) `MessageToSend` is still attached to the original session started in parent thread. However if the parent thread completed iteration (we exited `sendAllMessages()`) but the child `MessageSender` is still running, you'll get transient errors as above. "`session closed`" basically means parent thread closed the session before the child thread finished processing.

In simple words, you should never let objects bound to Hibernate session to escape from current thread. Instead detach them from session explicitly (e.g. by clearing the session or moving the transaction further up so that your objects are not attached to the session when you are iterating over them) and start new transaction for each processed row.

<sup>*</sup> - it seems like you are creating a new thread for each and every SMS you want to send. This is not very scalable, your system will fall once the total number of messages to send reaches several thousand. Instead use  a thread pool ([`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)).

Comment: I dont understand how detach the objects from session explicitly in my architecture.